# string expression to c# function delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, func

I want to convert the following string into function delegate.

```
[Id]-[Description]
```

C# class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Result function delegate:

```
Func<Foo, string> GetExpression = delegate()
{
    return x => string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.Id, x.Description);
};
```

I think compiled lambda or expression parser would be a way here, but not sure about the best way much. Any inputs?

Comment: Why don't you overwrite the `ToString()` method?

Comment: @asd since OP needs a delegate which can be executed from other places, by passing relevant Input

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a delegate and not just make a generic function that will parse the string for you?

Comment: You're asking how to *parse* some syntax and produce an executable something - that could be a delegate, a function or something that knows about Foo and tries to access the properties

Comment: `Func<Foo, string> GetExpression = x => string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.Id, x.Description)`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think OP wants the Func to be created on the fly based on the example string given in the first line

Comment: Yes. I can have some more complex string combination and need to reuse a function which can always produce a function delegate for me.

Comment: But why do you want a function delegate? Writing a simple function to do this (with a bunch of `string.Replace` for example) is very easy. Is there a reason you need a function?

Comment: @DavidG To speed it up significantly for many subsequent calls I guess.

Comment: @GSerg Yup, that's a possible option, but unless OP is doing this millions of times, I doubt there will be any noticeable perf issue.

Comment: Yes. I will have to deal with millions of items actually. And also there will be say 10 such expressions used in them.

Comment: Have you tried to create a simple method and check the performance?

Comment: @JayNanavaty It should not be too difficult to build an expression at runtime, but you will need a complete parser for your format string, for which you will need to formalize that format first. I doubt it is always two parts in brackets with one hyphen between them?

Comment: Usually relevant in performance questions: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @DavidG I have not tried that yet.

Comment: I would suggest you try it, you may find it is fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: @GSerg Yes. string can be anything like: [Id]_constantText[Description]-x

Comment: Check my latest Answer, it goes into the details of how to create an Expression Tree from Scratch for any case, by using the Expression details via visualizer and converting the same into code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible as: to construct Linq Expression then compile it. Compiled expression is an ordinary delegate, with no performance drawbacks.

An example of implementation if type of argument(`Foo`) is known at compile time:

```
class ParserCompiler
{
    private static (string format, IReadOnlyCollection<string> propertyNames) Parse(string text)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(.*?)\[(.+?)\](.*)");

        var formatTemplate = new StringBuilder();
        var propertyNames = new List<string>();
        var restOfText = text;
        Match match;
        while ((match = regex.Match(restOfText)).Success)
        {
            formatTemplate.Append(match.Groups[1].Value);
            formatTemplate.Append("{");
            formatTemplate.Append(propertyNames.Count);
            formatTemplate.Append("}");

            propertyNames.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);

            restOfText = match.Groups[3].Value;
        }

        formatTemplate.Append(restOfText);

        return (formatTemplate.ToString(), propertyNames);
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetExpression<T>(string text) //"[Id]-[Description]"
    {
        var parsed = Parse(text); //"{0}-{1}  Id, Description"

        var argumentExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var properties = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetField)
            .ToDictionary(keySelector: propInfo => propInfo.Name);

        var formatParamsArrayExpr = Expression.NewArrayInit(
            typeof(object), 
            parsed.propertyNames.Select(propName => Expression.Property(argumentExpression, properties[propName])));

        var formatStaticMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null,new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) }, null);
        var formatExpr = Expression.Call(
            formatStaticMethod,
            Expression.Constant(parsed.format, typeof(string)),
            formatParamsArrayExpr);

        var resultExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(
            formatExpr,
            argumentExpression); // Expression<Func<Foo, string>> a = (Foo x) => string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.Id, x.Description);

        return resultExpr.Compile();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
        var func = ParserCompiler.GetExpression<Foo>("[Id]-[Description]");
        var formattedString = func(new Foo {Id = "id1", Description = "desc1"});
```

Comment: Ah, yes, it just queries each property as many times as it is mentioned in the format string... the one I was going to post calls each property once ;)

Answer (score 2):

An almost identical answer [was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187529/11683) while I was testing this, but, as the below code has an advantage of calling each property mentioned in the formatting string at most once, I'm posting it anyway:

```
public static Func<Foo, string> GetExpression(string query_string)
{
    (string format_string, List<string> prop_names) = QueryStringToFormatString(query_string);

    var lambda_parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo));

    Expression[] formatting_params = prop_names.Select(
        p => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(lambda_parameter, typeof(Foo).GetProperty(p))
     ).ToArray();

    var formatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) });

    var format_call = Expression.Call(formatMethod, Expression.Constant(format_string), Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), formatting_params));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(format_call, lambda_parameter) as Expression<Func<Foo, string>>;
    return lambda.Compile();
}

// A *very* primitive parser, improve as needed
private static (string format_string, List<string> ordered_prop_names) QueryStringToFormatString(string query_string)
{
    List<string> prop_names = new List<string>();

    string format_string = Regex.Replace(query_string, @"\[.+?\]", m => {
        string prop_name = m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2);

        var known_pos = prop_names.IndexOf(prop_name);

        if (known_pos < 0)
        {
            prop_names.Add(prop_name);
            known_pos = prop_names.Count - 1;
        }

        return $"{{{known_pos}}}";
    });

    return (format_string, prop_names);
}
```

The inspiration comes from [Generate lambda Expression By Clause using string.format in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408160/11683).

Answer (score 1):

> **A simple step by step version to create an Expression tree based on simple use case, can help in creating any kind of Expression tree**

**What we want to Achieve: (coding in linqpad, Dump is a print call)**

```
Expression<Func<Foo,string>> expression = (f) => string.Format($"{f.Id}- 
{f.Description}"); 

var foo = new Foo{Id = "1",Description="Test"};

var func  = expression.Compile();

func(foo).Dump(); // Result "1-Test"

expression.Dump();
```

> **Following is the Expression generated:**

[image]

> **Step by Step process to Create an Expression Tree**

On Reviewing the Expression Tree, following points can be understood:

1. We create a Func delegate of type `typeof(Func<Foo,String>)`
2. Outer Node Type for Expression is `Lambda Type`
3. Just needs one parameter Expression of `typeof(Foo)`
4. In Arguments it needs, `MethodInfo` of `string.Format`
5. In arguments to Format method, it needs following Expressions
6. a.) Constant Expression - `{0}-{1}`
7. b.) MemberExpression for `Id` field
8. c.) MemberExpression for `Description` field
9. Viola and we are done

> Using the Steps above following is the simple code to create Expression:

```
// Create a ParameterExpression
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo),"f");

// Create a Constant Expression
var formatConstant  = Expression.Constant("{0}-{1}");

// Id MemberExpression
var idMemberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Id"));

// Description MemberExpression         
var descriptionMemberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Description"));

// String.Format (MethodCallExpression)
var formatMethod = Expression.Call(typeof(string),"Format",null,formatConstant,idMemberAccess,descriptionMemberAccess);

// Create Lambda Expression
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo,string>>(formatMethod,parameterExpression);

// Create Func delegate via Compilation
var func = lambda.Compile();

// Execute Delegate 
func(foo).Dump(); // Result "1-Test"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful to understand how it works and helps creating complex ones easily.

Comment: Yes though you need a **Expression Tree Visualizer** as it goes about solving the issue in reverse direction, **Linqpad** is good and there are others too like [Expression Tree Visualizer](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Expression-Tree-Visualizer), but a very good way to construct from Scratch, Happy Programming